# Rendering meta tags for a scraper in an client side (Angular JS) app

Tags: javascript, facebook, node.js, angularjs, client-side

I've got an `AngularJS` web app, which is basically running totally on the client side of course.
I need to add html `meta tags` for the `FaceBook` scraper, which of course needs it rendered from the server, and not from any client-side java-script.

So far I've done this using two different addresses :

So if someone surfs to `mysite.com/products/1234`
He will get the FaceBook meta tags and a redirect to `mysite.com/products2/1234`,
which is the client side app.

Of course this is not pretty and also when people copy-paste the link on their screen in FB - it won't find any meta data.

My App is `AngularJS`, server is `NodeJS`.

Is the only way to go server-side-rendering of the whole app page ?

I'd really love to keep client-side and server-side logic and code separate.

Thanks

Comment: Do you use html5 mode of angular or have each page has own view?

Comment: Each 'page' has it's own view, but of course the FaceBook scraper gets only the index.html

Answer (score 0):

I'm not familiar with node.js (yet :) ) but I'm pretty sure that you can check that a request is an XMLHttpRequest or not. If it is you send back the data for the ajax call if not you render the whole page.